# IllegalArgumentException when execute activity Transition Anim

Tags: android, android-activity

error log  as follow

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1624)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.isTopOfTask(ActivityManagerNative.java:4907)
at android.app.Activity.isTopOfTask(Activity.java:5691)
at android.app.Activity.cancelInputsAndStartExitTransition(Activity.java:4029)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4006)
at android.support.v4.app.j.startActivityForResult(SourceFile:54)
at android.support.v4.app.n.startActivityForResult(SourceFile:65)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4266)
```

looks like something wrong when execute animtion , but i don't know how to solve this. by the way ,i use this to start activity

```
 ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) context, sharedElements);
 ActivityCompat.startActivity(context, intent, optionsCompat.toBundle());
```

need
 help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not cast context from activity:

```
ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(context, sharedElements);
ActivityCompat.startActivity(context, intent, optionsCompat.toBundle());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = 
    ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) context, sharedElements);
    ActivityCompat.startActivity(context, intent, optionsCompat.toBundle());
} else {
   startActivity(context, intent);
}
```